# Arquivo Proguard.cfg Android

Tags: android, proguard-android

Como eu faço para "ofuscar" as minhas classes, métodos, variáveis e etc no arquivo de configuração do Android proguard.cfg? Meu intuito é de dificultar a descompilação (engenharia reversa) do projeto.

Comment: Olha, por default o `ProGuard` já faz a obfuscação de tudo. Em geral num projeto você tem um arquivo chamado `proguard-rules.txt` no Android Studio mas pode ser `proguard.cfg`. É muito comum se configurar métodos/classes que não devem ser obfuscados porque atrapalha no uso de `Reflection`, e isso é/deveria ser divulgado pelo criador de bibliotecas de terceiros. Dependendo de qual sistema de Build esta usando, seja Ant ou Gradle, há formas diferentes de configurar a execução dependendo do tipo do build (release ou debug).

Comment: Ahh, legal. Vlw pela informação. Acredito que o default seja suficiente então...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A engenharia reversa do seu código, quando configurado pelo Proguard em default, pode ser obtida seguindo esse simples tutorial:
http://ebortolin.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/engenharia-reversa-de-aplicativos-android/

Gaste um pouco mais de tempo configurando o seu Proguard corretamente para ofuscar ainda mais seu código. Um bom link que demonstra como configurar o seu Proguard corretamente segue abaixo:
https://github.com/exmo/equizmo-android/wiki/Ofuscando-aplicativos-Android

Comment: Muito bom!!!!!!